# PHP send email to wrong account

Tags: php, forms, email

My PHP code works, but not perfect. When I respond my form and send the answer instead of send the text to my email server or from contact, he sends to my personal email. This is strange because my personal email is out of my code, he is not mentioned in any code line. I checked my server account and don't exist any redirection to other email.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function pegaValor($valor) {
    return isset($_POST[$valor]) ? $_POST[$valor] : '';
}

function validaEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

function enviaEmail($de, $assunto, $corpo, $para, $email_servidor) {
    $headers = "From: $email_servidor\r\n" .
               "Reply-To: $de\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  mail($para, $assunto, nl2br($corpo), $headers);
}

$email_servidor = "eduarda@getescala.com";
$para = "eduarda@getescala.com";
$assunto = "Contato do Site - GetEscala";
$de = pegaValor("email");
$objetivos = pegaValor("objetivos");
$ondeanuncia = pegaValor("onde-anuncia");
$leads = pegaValor("leads");
$investimento = pegaValor("investimento");
$site = pegaValor("site");
$nome = pegaValor("nome");
$email = pegaValor("email");
$telefone = pegaValor("telefone");


$corpo = "Objetivos: " . $objetivos . "\n\n" . "Onde anuncia: " . $ondeanuncia . "\n\n" . "Leads ou vendas: " . $leads . "\n\n" . "Investimento: " . $investimento . "\n\n" . "Site: " . $site . "\n\n" . "Nome: " . $nome . "\n\n" . "E-mail: " . $email . "\n\n" . "Telefone: " . $telefone ;

if (validaEmail($de)) {
    enviaEmail($de, $assunto, $corpo, $para, $email_servidor);
    $pagina = "mail_ok.php";
} else {
    $pagina = "mail_error.php";
}

header("Location: $pagina");
```

Comment: What do you see if you view the headers of the email you receive? What's in the `Reply-to` field?

Comment: When I opened the email on gmail this is the header > from: eduarda@getescala.com and the email who is sending is eduarda@getescala.com

Comment: You have `"Reply-To: $de\r\n"` that's where replies will be sent. Are you not seeing this in the full header?

Comment: I'm not understand your point. The part with "Reply-to: ... " is for who I will respond, all right? My problem is why I can't receive the email in my email account specified in the code.

Comment: You wrote **When I respond my form** so I thought you were talking about replying to the email that the form sends.

Comment: Can you check the outgoing mail log on your server, to see where it's sending the mail?

Comment: Sorry, I mean: When I write in my form in my web page and click to send the response.

Comment: I understand that now. I don't see anything in the code that would do that, so it must be coming from a PHP or mailer configuration.

Comment: Does this only happen when you try to send to your email server, or when you send any email from PHP?

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie. I don't have sure how I can make this. I only have my files .html, .css, .js and .php hosteds in a cPanel. When I click in send the form, other page is loaded (mail_ok.php) and the data in console and network from chrome is cleaned.

Comment: For testing I use emails like a@b.c, teste@gmail.com, nothing like my personal email who received the content.

Comment: I don't use cPanel. Here's what I found when I googled how to view mail log: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/outgoing-email-log.107661/

Comment: I found a config in email panel account in cPanel and I was not know yet about her. I did delete the forward and I'm waiting to discover what is the mail box to receive the new answer. The receiving is a little bit lazy now, when I having a solution I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution:

My server email on cPanel was ignoring the solicitation to send the email to an external server (like gmail). Because I have the redirection on cPanel for eduarda@getescala.com to my personal email, I received the answer in other email.

tl;dr I change the redirection to another professional account, but don't a account with the same domain.